# Java Reg expression for replacing img tag with ending tag

Tags: java, html, regex

i want reg expression to replace  html  tag with close tag like :

```
<img src="path"> with <img src="path" /> or <img src="path" ></img>
```

Please i need this because i need this proper html using for Itext pdf generator api it need proper ending tags .. please give me solution

Comment: Which of the two do you want? What have you tried? Why didn't that work?

Comment: i want output as ending tag for img

Comment: end tags for images are always the same </img>, why would you need to generate them based on a start tag?

Comment: No when i print inner html it generate like <img src="" > but i need it to be replaced with <img src="" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find:**

```
(<img[^>]*[^/]>)(?!\s*</img>)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1</img>
```

This makes sure that you're not screwing up tags that already close 
**e.g** You do not want to replace `<img src="path"></img>` with `<img src="path"></img></img>`

In Java I believe the code **might** be:

```
str.replaceAll("(<img[^>]*[^/]>)(?!\\s*</img>)", "$1</img>");
```

Comment: Nice catch with watching out for already closed tags.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for but maybe instead of regex try using HTML parser? [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) seems to return something similar to what you are looking for.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<img src=\"path\"><div>something");
System.out.println(doc);
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <img src="path" />
  <div>
   something
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But my path will be changed each time so how to handle it ??? @pshemo

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar What do you mean by each time? Please update your question and include more informations because I am not sure what is problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to change all `<img >` tags to `<img />` tags, you can use the following sed command, but as others pointed out it's not really a good idea, it can easily go wrong.

```
sed "s/\(<\s*img.*\)>/\1\/>/" Your_File.html
```

Comment: i want it as java string

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *"want it as java string"* ?

Comment: i mean img tag is in java string variable and now i want to replace in that java string